# Why does FaceTime ring on all my devices? Have tried everything!

Tags: iphone, facetime

when my daughter receives a FaceTime call from one of her friends (now that I think about it it may be only this one friend), my iPhone, my husband's iPhone, and my iPad all ring.  I set up separate iCloud accounts for all of us and turned off cellular calling on my iPad. There doesn't seem to be an option to do this on the iPhone any longer. Despite these efforts,  all of our devices still ring when my daughter gets a FaceTime call from her friend. What should I do next?

Comment: When changing an appleId on a device there are actually like 7 areas in settings that it needs to be changed. FaceTime is one of those.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the same AppleID on all the devices. The default is that all devices configured with the same AppleID use the *primary email address* associated with that Apple ID.

You have a couple of options:

1. Use a different AppleID
2. Use a different email other than the primary one.  There's an [excellent article](http://ipad.about.com/od/iPad_Guide/ss/How-To-Use-FaceTime-On-The-iPad.htm#step2) on how to do this workaround

Basically, you go into the Facetime settings on on each device you don't want to ring and add another (different) email.

Comment: I actually already read that article and followed its advice. Each of us has a separate Apple ID and email.  Still rings for all devices when my daughter gets a FaceTime call.